# Trouble inserting record with a one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm learning C# and Entity Framework using WinForms with Code First. I'm trying to insert a record into the database but I'm not having much luck. The problem has to do with the FK values. I have a product model that looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength( 50 )]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength( 300 )]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

    public int ReorderLevel { get; set; }

    public int TargetStockLevel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Cost { get; set; } 

    [StringLength( 400 )]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastEdited { get; set; }
}
```

Each product belongs to a category and a subcategory:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

When the user clicks the "Save" button, the following code is executed:

```
    // Create a new product
    var product = new Product();
    product.ProductCode = txtProductCode.Text;
    product.Description = txtDescription.Text;
    product.Category = int.Parse( cmboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString() ); // Error Here so the rest fails
    //product.Category.ID = int.Parse( cmboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString() ); I tried this also...
    product.SubCategory.ID = int.Parse( cmboSubCategory.SelectedValue.ToString() );
    product.ReorderLevel = int.Parse( txtReorderLevel.Text );
    product.TargetStockLevel = int.Parse( txtTargetStock.Text );
    product.Pieces = int.Parse( txtPieces.Text );
    product.Cost = double.Parse( txtCost.Text );
    product.Note = txtNotes.Text;
    product.Active = true;
    product.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    product.LastEdited = DateTime.Now;

    // Create the new Product
    using ( var db = new InventoryContext() )
    {
        db.Products.Add( product );
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

As the above code stands above VS gives an error:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'InventoryTracker.DataModels.Category'"
```

I know this has to be simple, I'm just not getting it and my Google-fu is failing me today. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment @skalinkin. I realize that my lack of familiarity with C# is a large part of the problem, that's why I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @skalinkin well, he's trying to become familiar with it, and that's what's bringing him to asking this question

Comment: Etymology: "Google-fu" is probably derived from Kung-Fu, with the implication that both are arts to be mastered.

Answer (score 0):

`product.Category` is not the foreign key.  Is a navigation property.  It is there so that you can treat `it like a typical object while EF does the hard work for you.  It does not actually exist in your products table.

Instead, entity framework adds it's own int value(Category_ID), which is a foreign key reference to a categories table.

If you want to set the foreign key directly, I'd declare `Category` like this

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

...

[ForeignKey("Category")]
public int CategoryId { get; set; }

public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

that way, if you want to set your id, you set it this way

```
product.CategoryId = int.Parse( cmboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString() );
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam I am. If I look at the Products table I see Category_ID as the FK and it is an int, do I need to do some sort of lookup before I can insert the record? Sorry, I'm just not catching it.